# Is there a way to access chrome extension background pages on Cypress?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, cypress

I'm interested in seeing the network tab in an extension's background page while running tests using Cypress.

When I go to chrome://extensions and click background page within the Cypress browser nothing pops up. I've also tried navigating directly to chrome-extension://(extension-id)/_generated_background_page.html but this stops the extension from working entirely.

Comment: Try launching the browser with `--remote-debugging-port=9222` command line, then open `http://localhost:9222` and inspect from there.

Comment: Thanks, this is what I was looking for! Only issue is the websocket loses connection pretty frequently and the page stops tracking requests, that might be a different question altogether though.